# How to re-download an email in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My company runs a Microsoft Exchange email system, with Outlook 2010 on the computers.  On my machine, I have an email with an attached file that is corrupted.  However, the file as it exists on the server is not corrupted.  So, I'd like to re-download this specific email so that the .ost file on my machine is correct.  I'd rather not delete the .ost file on my local machine since I have several GB of emails, which seems to be the sticking point here, as I cannot find an approach that doesn't rely on this.  Is there any option to simply re-download an email?  If possible, this would solve this sort of problem under any circumstances, which is why I'm after a solution of this type.  In my particular case, I can download the file from the server myself, so I'm not actually being prevented from accessing the data.

Comment: Have you asked your IT department to send you the un-corrupted file or asked the sender of the original email to send it again? I would start there because they can probably get this done pretty quickly.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/89380/how-do-i-download-all-existing-email-on-an-exchange-server-to-outlook

Comment: @RayM I'm looking for a more general solution to re-download the file, since it's always possible that other methods might not work under other circumstances.  Though, there may not be a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's Exchange, access it via OWA (webmail), or [turn off your Outlook cache](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-or-off-Cached-Exchange-Mode-78c1b9a7-9677-4655-ab97-d20ca35e29f9) for that Exchange account and restart Outlook.

Doing either of these will give you a live view of the email directly on the server.

Perhaps check out this related SU question:

- [What's the impact of undoing Cached Exchange Mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/247022/whats-the-impact-of-undoing-cached-exchange-mode)

Comment: I'm looking specifically to fix the existing copy of the file in the .ost database.  I don't want to run the risk of forgetting and using the bad data 6 months from now.

Comment: +1 for OWA - this is a sure shot way of looking directly into the server